# Entire Wordpress theme reset to default after server upload

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a Wordpress website, customized its CSS and PHP, uploaded images, set up Woocommerce etc. When I uploaded it to server, all the changes I have made were lost. Also, woocommerce pages stopped working with this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@mysite.com to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The way I uploaded it:

1. uploaded **.htacces** to public_html
2. uploaded the wordpress directory contents to the same folder
3. exported the .sql database from local phpMyAdmin
4. replaced all *localhost/mysite/wordpress* and *localhost:8012/mysite/wordpress* to *www.mysite.com* (the port is specified because there was a problem with apache, so I had to configure it)
5. created a database in cpanel
6. created a user in cpanel
7. changed db_name, db_user and db_password in **wp_config.php** file (entered the values in prefix_name format)
8. added the user to database in cpanel with all privileges
9. in phpMyAdmin on server imported the database

I used FileZilla, if relevant.

This is not the first time I'm doing this, and I had problems before, but not like this. I heard it had something to do with collation, but I tried changing it - no luck.

Disclaimer: **I SEARCHED THE GOOGLE AND RELEVANT ANSWERS HERE WERE NO HELP EITHER**

Answer (score 1):

Check **AllowOverride** key in apache httpd.conf ( or http.conf ) it must be **ALL** not **none**